# Warning in useEffect function even though i am not using it in my screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am getting a warning message when i login. if i comment setIsLoading(true) then its working. I guess my state is getting updated before the component is mounted. I dont use useEffect function here, its just direct button click. how do i clean up my warning?

Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function

```
const SignInScreen = () => {
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const authHandler = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    await dispatch(AuthReducer.signIn(uname, pwd));
    setIsLoading(false);
  };
};
```

JSX,

```
return (
{isLoading ? (
              <ActivityIndicator size="small"/> ) : (
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={authHandler}>
                Login
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )}
);
```

Action method,

```
export const signIn = (username, password) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const response1 = await axios.post("/Mobile/mlogin", {uname,pwd});
 const response2 = await axios.post("...............);
 const response3 = await axios.get(...............);
catch(err)
{}
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should clean - what they call - subscriptions.
In your case that would be something like that:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true

    const authHandler = async () => {
     if (mounted) {
      setIsLoading(true)
      await dispatch(AuthReducer.signIn(uname, pwd))
      setIsLoading(false)
     } 
    }

    authHandler()

    return () => mounted = false;

  }, []);
```

Read here for reference:
[https://www.debuggr.io/react-update-unmounted-component/#:~:text=Warning%3A%20Can't%20perform%20a,in%20a%20useEffect%20cleanup%20function](https://www.debuggr.io/react-update-unmounted-component/#:%7E:text=Warning%3A%20Can%27t%20perform%20a,in%20a%20useEffect%20cleanup%20function).

Comment: Possible to handle this without using useEffect hook?

Comment: Because authHandler is calling upon button onPress event.